# Why is my backend C# code getting executed when it should not be?

Tags: javascript, c#

Geniuses,

I have this Javascript function in my front end code and I am trying to push more client side validation steps there to relieve by backend from too much validation work. Here is the Javascript function:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
    function watchdelete() {
        var manufacturer = document.getElementById('<%:drpManufacturer.ClientID%>');
        var model = document.getElementById('<%:drpModel.ClientID%>');
        var strManufacturer = manufacturer.options[manufacturer.selectedIndex].value;
        var strModel = model.options[model.selectedItem];
        if (strManufacturer)   // If there is a selected Manufacturer
        {
            if (confirm("Are you Sure you want to delete this Dimension Detail?"))
            {
                if (strModel) return true;
                else
                {
                    alert("Please select a car model first.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Please select a Manufacturer first before deleting");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scripman1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Here is the delete button code in question with the OnclientClick pointing to the Javascript function and the Onclick pointing to the backend function:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDimensionDel" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick = "watchdelete();" OnClick="btnDimensionDel_Click" />
```

I notice that my backend C# code is getting called when it should not be. Is there anything I can do to change this? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You could use a `OnClientClick="return watchdelete();"` statement to only execute when your watchdelete() returns true

Comment: Smarty pants. That is the right answer. You need to insert the word return and return false, otherwise it executes c# backend code as well. Thanks for that. I found out the answer shortly afterwards. No hurt in sharing though.

Comment: If you're using web forms, you should be using the build in validation controls, they handle clientside and serverside validation, and you should not rely on client side validation only. The extra load serverside for a few lines of validation is negligible. The main advantage of client side validation is a smoother user experience.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Make sure to insert the keyword return before your OnclientClick function and return false from your Javascript function so that C# backend will not be called.

Answer (score -1):

On button's event, you are calling a js method, nothing else. so, after executing your specified method, the browser would execute the default behavior for the button. if you want to avoid this, you have to for example use this: `OnClientClick = "watchdelete(); return false;"` but, since your method is returning something to handling the situation, so simply you can return your method's return value:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnDimensionDel" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick = "return watchdelete();" OnClick="btnDimensionDel_Click" />
```

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could *edit your answer* and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: @TarynEast My English is too bad. so the explanation would be a mess :)

Comment: Hey, it's not too bad - a bit of explanation is better than none, even if we have to puzzle out what you're trying to say ;)